# what does "delete from table where NULL = NULL" means?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sql-delete

What does `delete from table where NULL = NULL` mean?

Comment: It means that you're on a job interview.

Answer (score 37):

That will delete nothing from the table.
NULL does not equal NULL.

Now

> delete from table where NULL is NULL

*would* delete all rows from the table.

Comment: +1 for NULL != NULL.  A bit more explanation, since I like this distinction.  In database terms, NULL can mean a lack of information -- i.e. not provided, for whatever reason -- or unknown information, but you don't know which.  Therefore, no two NULLs are alike.

Comment: Right, and two NULLs are also not unalike.  If you don't know the values, you can't say for sure whether they're the same or whether they're different.  Hence any comparison yields *unknown* which is not *false* but it's definitely not *true* either.

Comment: +1 But with one caveat. It is so only in standard SQL and not all RDBMS provide the same standard dialect of SQL. I didn't post it as an answer, because the question is tagged _mysql_, but in MS SQL Server if you first issue `set ansi_nulls off` then `delete from table when null = null` will delete all rows because with this switch `null = null` becomes true.

Answer (score 16):

It means don't delete anything, because NULL is never equal to anything. Or maybe it means "don't delete anything unless the user's DBMS really sucks, in which case delete it all out of spite".

Seriously though, that kind of construct usually comes about when a WHERE clause is procedurally generated -- rather than creating a special case for "do nothing", sometimes it's simpler just to generate a WHERE clause that causes the database to do nothing. I've usually seen "WHERE 0 = 1" though, which is less ambiguous.

Comment: +1 for the guessing about the generated query - which was the 1st thing that came on my mind when I read the question.

Answer (score 8):

In SQL, there are three logical values, namely TRUE, FALSE, and UNKNOWN.  when we compare null to null, using null=null, the operation will return UNKNOWN. Moreover,In the WHERE clause all UNKNOWN values  are filtered  out.Hence the query does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

It punishes people who have ANSI_NULLS set to off in their database :)

Answer (score 3):

Since NULL does not equal NULL, this statement will do nothing. It equals:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Recap:

```
mysql> select null = null, null <> null, null is null, null = 1, null <> 1;
+-------------+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
| null = null | null <> null | null is null | null = 1 | null <> 1 |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
|        NULL |         NULL |            1 |     NULL |      NULL |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select count(*) from table;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     10   |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.33 sec)


mysql> select * from table where null;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Meaning, if a condition evaluates to null it is considered false by MySql so `delete from table where NULL = NULL` will in fact delete nothing.

NULL is a special beast as noted by [Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))

Comment: isn't it a bit confusing to state that null is considered false (since NOT null would then have to be true, which isn't the case)?

Comment: yes its confusing, but im specifically talking about conditions here. but the whole null thing is super confusing.

Comment: null is not considered false, but also it's not considered true. WHERE checks if expression evaluates to true.

Comment: Null represents the fact that you don't know a value. You can't say that something you don't know equals another thing that you don't know. Likewise, you can't say that that those two things don't equal one another. Strictly speaking NULL = NULL should evaluate to NULL because you don't know whether those two things are equal or not. False however is good enough for most cases.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it depends on the database, but to my knowledge, it shouldn't achieve anything, as NULL is never equal to NULL, at least in db theory.

Answer (score -2):

Not a single row is affected by this SQL command.