# Data Comparing in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a front end developer in .net i have a question about the data comparison in SQ L  whether it compares by value or by reference.

> SELECT 1 WHERE NULL =NULL 
>   --> No Result
>
> SELECT 1 WHERE 1=1
>   --> Return the result 1.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201192/what-does-delete-from-table-where-null-null-means

Comment: `WHERE NULL IS NULL`

Comment: The best thing you can do as a developer coming from .NET to SQL is to *forget everything you know about null* as just about none of it applies. In SQL all things are compared *"by value"*. When it comes to null SQL interprets this semantically as any one of *missing information*, *unknown information*, or *information not provided*. The distinction is very subtle yet hugely important. Consider reading a primer on relational set theory before you do much more SQL work.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is done by value, but I think where you're getting confused is with `NULL` values which really mean "a missing value".

To compare against `NULL`, you'll want to use `col_name IS NULL` or `col_name IS NOT NULL` instead of the standard `=` or `!=` operators.

For MySQL, refer to the [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) documentation. T-SQL has less of a reference with [`IS [NOT] NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx)